# Save LinkedList to file and Load List back to program

Tags: java, file, file-io, linked-list

I have a stock control system being used and i have a LinkedList to hold stock objects, now i need to add a method to the program that will allow me to save the linked list to a file and load the list from the file.

```
public void loadStockData(String filename)
```

and

```
public void saveStockData()
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at `File`, `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream`. `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: Yes i have tried these, and it allways goes wrong for me, I either get an end of file exeption or i get that the object is not serializable or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your objects support serialization, hint: `implements Serializable`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Then, use java.io.ObjectOutputStream to save and java.io.ObjectInputStream to read the list.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: I will try this today, and ill get back if i get any problems, Thank You

Comment: Hi, can u share the code for saving the Linked List to file.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention if the file should be human readable.

If not then serialize the `LinkedList` object itself to the file given that the object it contains is also `Serializable`. You can use [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29) to do that. Provide a `FileOutputStream` to the `ObjectOutputStream`

If you need in some specific format then you need to write the logic and using `FileOutputStream` you can write the file.

Comment: The file doesnt have to be human readable, All i want is when i use the save method the LinkedList is saved and load loads the linked list, But i want to be able to use the objects in the list using an interface that i am currentyl bu8lding.

Comment: Then use the serialization process I have mentioned. What interface you are talking about?

Comment: Just a menu one where the user can add stock, view stock ect

Comment: So one the LinkedList is deserialized you have the information in java object so you can use it the way you want. But if you really want to maintain stock where it can be removed/added then use some database. It would be easy to manage that way.

Comment: I have to use a linked list and a file, as im doing file handling. Thanks